# How to implement a Gaussian function in field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, statistics

Are there any build-in functions like Gaussian or Epanechnikov functions in field calculator?  Or I have to write that by myself?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with it and what would you be running it on?

Comment: These functions seem to be present elsewhere in ArcGIS for Desktop  i.e. as Kernel Functions in the [Geostatistical Analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00310000002z000000) extension

Comment: Which makes me think that the functions are there cleverly disguised by a different name.

Comment: Thank you.  Ya I know that, but I just want to do it within the attribute table.

Comment: I just want to add a field, and assign a weighted population value using those kinds of kernel functions.

Comment: I'm not an expert on statistical functions to understand the subtleties of one function over the other but I'd go with what @PolyGeo said. Follow the link to the GeoStatistical Analyst Toolbox; it may not be just a simple field calculation but those methods are well published and are likely to be referenced in that toolbox.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelMiles-Stimson.  I think I may have to write the funtion myself in the calculator.

Comment: Thank you @PolyGeo.  I think I may have to write the funtion myself in the calculator.

Comment: When you've got that working properly consider answering your own question. Other users may encounter the same problem and could benefit from it.

Comment: Haha, OK.  Game rule here right?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to perform a density estimate. How do you propose doing that with the field calculator? Although in principle that would be possible, it would take so many iterations as to be impracticable except in toy cases, so I am wondering whether you really perhaps ought to be asking a different question altogether in which you describe your data, explain what you would like to achieve, and see what responses you get back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should note that field calculator applies only row by row (except if you use a static variable).

So you will need to precompute the mean and the standard deviation of your Gaussian distribution. Then run the equation in Python

```
def Gaussian(field, mean, std):
    return math.exp(-(field-mean)**2/(2*std**2))/(math.sqrt(math.pi()*2)*std)
```

Gaussian(!field!, mean, std)

for Epanechnikov,

```
def Epan(field, size):
    if math.fabs(field) >= size:
        return 0
    else:
        return 3*(1-(field/size)**2)/4
```

Epan(!field!, size)